# How to set up for merged mining

Tags: mining-pools, merged-mining

I plan to eventually add litecoin, Dogecoin, and possibly some other scrypt merged-minable coins to my pool. Are there any tutorials or other information available that would show me how to set my pool up for merged mining?

Comment: Are you asking how to turn on merged mining in the configuration of some mining pool software you are using? If so, which one? Or are you asking how to add merged mining to pool software that you are developing?

Comment: Currently, I'm using NOMP for my pool, and I understand that NOMP doesn't support merged mining. What I'm wanting to know is if there is any currently available software that supports merged mining or will I need a custom solution. Also, I've had trouble finding much information on the subject and am interested in learning how this is implemented on the pool's side.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/KillerByte/node-merged-pool), which supports merged mining.